# trouble geting jlink to load a module

Tags: java, jlink

I am following through a Java textbook, and is stuck when running some example code that uses Jlink to "create a runtime image" of a group of modules.

I have a directory structure that looks kind of like this, with `appfuncs` and `appstart` being 2 modules that I have defined where `appstart` requires the appfuncs module, and `appstart` also contains the point of entry main class, `MyModAppDemo.java.`

[image]

When I run the jLink command below, i get an error that says that the mymodapp module cannot be loaded.

```
jlink --launcher MyModApp=appstart/appstart.mymodappdemo.MyModAppDemo --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%"\jmods;mymodapp\appmodules --add-modules appstart --output mylinkedmodapp
```

The error:
[image]

I hope to get some idea of what this error is about, if I am missing something that is really fundamental I am really sorry, I'm not very proficient with Java.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.  Edit your question and paste your error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a powershell error, not a Java error.

The issue is  that in powershell, `;` is used to delimit commands. To prevent that, you need to use quotes. Furthermore, you can't use `%JAVA_HOME%` in powershell to access environment variables. You need to use `$Env:JAVA_HOME` instead. This should work:

```
jlink --launcher MyModApp=appstart/appstart.mymodappdemo.MyModAppDemo --module-path "$Env:JAVA_HOME\jmods;mymodapp\appmodules" --add-modules appstart --output mylinkedmodapp
```